# Whats the difference between ORM and ORP?

Tags: object, orm, persistence

What is the difference between Object Relational Mapping(ORM) and Object Relational Persistence(ORP)?

From what i know ORM is a framework for mapping relational tables to application domain objects and relationships between them. So in ORM you would already have a Persistent data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORP consists of:

- Entities
- Database connection
- Database
- Mapping (ORM)
- Etc..

We could almost say it is the same thing since ORM is a term which is used as ORP. Both are used to indicate the same thing.

Comment: It's time for a tag synonym.

Comment: @RTB Yes I agree on that